# How to display another view from an existing view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have an existing view displayed.  After displaying that view for 2 seconds, I want to navigate or display another view.  The following code does not work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
            UIImage(named: "ProfileSplashScreen")?.draw(in: self.view.bounds)
            let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2.0) {
        GameSelectorController()
}
//=====================================================
import SwiftUI

struct GameSelectorController: UIViewController {
    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}

struct GameSelectorController_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GameSelectorController()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure SwiftUI you would do something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showFirst = true
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if showFirst {
                StartView()
            } else {
                SecondView()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                self.showFirst = false
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StartView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("First")
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Second")
    }
}
```

Comment: How would one introduce a Controller in the above code?

Comment: It seems to me like you are mixing up UIKit and SwiftUI. There are ways to use UIKit for SwiftUI development but I wouldn't know how to use SwiftUI in an UIKit application. I would need more context to know what you need to make it work. You shouldn't even need to use a UIViewController when developing with SwiftUI.

Comment: You may be correct, as this is my first project on iOS.  When creating a new project I use a Storyboard  interface with a UIKit App delegate.  When I do this a default ViewController.swift, SceneDelegate.swift  and 2 storyboards are created (Main.storyboard and Launchscreen.storyboard).  If this is not the proper way, what options should be selected when creating a new project.  I am using Xcode 12.

Comment: When creating a new project, select the Interface to be "SwiftUI" and the Life Cycle to "SwiftUI App". It is on the same setup page where you choose the product name. The Launchscren.storyboard will still be created for a SwiftUI application but you only need that for creating a splash screen. Hope it works and enjoy learning SwiftUI.